# Find $lim_{x \to \pi} {\frac{\sin(x)}{e^{\pi}-e^x}}$ using series expansion

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, power-series, limits-without-lhopital

Using L'Hospital's Rule ($\frac{0}{0}$ Case):
$$\lim_{x \to \pi} {\frac{\sin(x)}{e^{\pi}-e^x}}=\lim_{x \to \pi} {\frac{\cos(x)}{-e^x}}=\frac{-1}{-e^{\pi}}=\frac{1}{e^{\pi}}$$

But can I also do this using series expansions. For example:

$$\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+...}{e^{\pi}-[e^{\pi}(x-\pi)+e^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}(x-\pi)^2+...]}$$

Which then simplifies to:
$$\lim_{x \to \pi} \frac{x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+...}{-e^{\pi}[(x-\pi)+\frac{1}{2}(x-\pi)^2+...]}$$

And now I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: You seem to have missed a “1-…” in the starting of the long factor of the denominator.

Comment: Dividing by an infinite series is messy. Try factoring out the $e^\pi$ and you'll have $(1-\blacksquare)^{-1}$.

Comment: If you are allowed to use the fact that $\sin x=\sin (\pi -x)$ then you can use the series for $\sin (\pi -x)$ and you will easily get the limit.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sure. But the numerator will have terms for x and x^3, and the denominator will have a term for x^2. Can you elaborate on your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Blitzer I factored out an $e^{pi}$ at a later stage. if you can show your method works, it would be great.$

Comment: For those ^2 and ^3, etc. terms, you can set them all to $0$. Since $(\pi-x)$ will be much bigger than those terms when x tends to $\pi$

Comment: @AbelWong And after that?

Comment: Use geetha290km's answer, you set $(x-\pi)^2, (x-\pi)^3$ terms to $0$, Then it becomes $\frac{-(x-\pi)}{-e^{\pi}(x-\pi)}=\frac{1}{e^\pi}$ which is the same as your result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that $\sin x=\sin (\pi -x)$. You have $\frac{(\pi -x)-\frac{(\pi -x)^3}{3!}+...}{-e^{\pi}[(x-\pi)+\frac{1}{2}(x-\pi)^2+...]}$. Cancel one factor of  $x-\pi$ from numerator and denominator and put $x=\pi$.